# Efficiently reduce a big np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to reduce a nonzero array of the type:

```
a = np.zeros([10**4,10**4])
```

To a lower number of dimensions (columns) conditional to a simple constraint of the type:

```
a[column_index].sum() > threshold
```

I could easily do it with by iterating and calling .delete but I am actually looking for something more efficient (since the array is quite big). Any hints?

Comment: Just to be clear, by "lower number of dimensions" you mean "fewer rows"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sum along axis 0 to get all columns sum, then create a bool array to select the columns:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 100, [100,100])
b = a[:, a.sum(axis=0) > 5000]
print b.sum(axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([5359, 5045, 5116, 5512, 5143, 5261, 5209, 5018, 5009, 5025, 5353,
       5149, 5407, 5258, 5148, 5527, 5176, 5173, 5028, 5110, 5406, 5211,
       5287, 5163, 5364, 5623, 5257, 5361, 5528, 5049, 5298, 5280, 5201,
       5099, 5314, 5071, 5318, 5076, 5005, 5032, 5194, 5411, 5329, 5293])
```

Comment: Really nice, I was exactly looking for an example of this type of filtering. Good job.